# Centered div with percent width shrinks under certain circumstances

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a site that places content inside a div with the following styling:

```
.container {
  padding-top: 40px; /*This is to leave space for a floating*/
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
}
```

This works fine on two pages but on a third one, the div shrinks to about half it's normal width, and I cant figure out why. The only obvious difference is that this page contains a list while the others are just paragraphs, but removing the list doesn't fix the problem. Here are two pens, the page that [works](http://codepen.io/CryptoMin/pen/Raqmvr) and the one that [doesn't](http://codepen.io/CryptoMin/pen/reQgZZ). The images are missing on the pens but the effect is the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: body is absolute with no width, add to it width:100%; so it fills entire width of page ... why absolute for body BTW ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKOBPB

Comment: restart without absolute but with margin:0; on body, so no need to find a funny hack ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `position:absolute` in body. In your working examples the text is wide enough so that your its achieving full width but in 3rd example text is small so there is a problem.

You need to assign `width:100%` in body or if there is no use just remove it.

Comment: Thanks, that was left there from before because i was waving trouble with margins collapsing. removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you use `position: absolute` for the `body`,  but if you take that out, your problem is fixed...

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: if you look at the comment in CSS of the OP, the initial problem comes certainly from the default margin of body, that can be fixed with margin:0; , then absolute is no longer needed :) . was waiting for him to answer my comment question. So from there, he can keep going on without thinking he found an hack but understood something http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWmdpw